# Linear search for an element within structures saved to file

Tags: c, file, data-structures, scanf, linear-search

I have a module which searches through a file to find an index, and if it's found it is supposed to print the details relevant to that index. The program compiles and runs, but no matter if the patient is saved or not, it prints that the patient is not found. What's the logic error I'm missing?

note:patientCount is a global variable which is written to another file and updated every time a patient is added.

```
void patientSearch(struct patientRec patient[], struct apptRec appt[])
{    
    system("cls");
    int c=0;
    char search[6], admit;

    printf("Enter the patient ID of the patient you would like to search for.\n");
    scanf("%i", &search);
    fflush(stdin);

    FILE *fp;

    fp=fopen("patients.txt", "r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError opening file!");
    }
    else
    {

        for (c=0; c<patientCount; c++)
        {
            if (search==patient[c].patientID)
            {
                printf("\nPatient found.\n\n");
                printf("Patient ID: %i", patient[c].patientID);

                fscanf(fp, "%s", patient[c].fName);
                printf("\nPatient First Name: ");
                puts(patient[c].fName);

                fscanf(fp, "%s", patient[c].sName);
                printf("\nPatient Surname: ");
                puts(patient[c].sName);

                fscanf(fp, "%i %c", patient[c].age, patient[c].sex);
                printf("\nPatient Age: %i\nPatient Sex: %c", patient[c].age, patient[c].sex);

                fscanf(fp, "%s", patient[c].notes);
                printf("\n\nNotes: \n");
                puts(patient[c].notes);
            }
            else
            {
                fscanf(fp, "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    if (c==patientCount)
    {
        printf("\nThis patient does not exist. Would you like to admit this patient?\n1: Yes\n2: No\n");
        scanf(" %c", &admit);
        if (admit=='1')
        {
            admitPatient(patient, appt);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: First problem: `scanf("%i", &search);`. That provides a pointer to a char array when a pointer to an int is required for the `%i` directive. Similarly `search==patient[c].patientID` is almost certainly wrong as it makes no sense to have an array as one of the comparator operands (don't know what `patientID` is as you have not provided complete code). Also, suggest you use a debugger to help you find the problem on your own.

Answer (score 1):

```
char search[6], admit;
scanf("%i", &search);
if (search==patient[c].patientID)
```

Either change to

```
int search; // This allows the rest of the code to match
```

or change to

```
char search[6], admit; //Change the rest of the code to match
scanf("%s", &search);
if (strcmp(search, patient[c].patientID) == 0)
printf("Patient ID: %s", patient[c].patientID);
```

To make your input and compare in the same format.

Make sure that your search array is big enough to include the final '\0'